# ionic 2 paypal plugin for multiple items

Tags: java, ionic-framework, paypal, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am using ionic 2

i am having issue sending multiple items to PayPalPayment i have tried this below code it's working fine without items,

```
let payment = new PayPalPayment('3.33', 'USD', 'Description', 'sale');
PayPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then(() => {
  //response ...
});
```

but it's not working well if i put items in it

```
let payment = new PayPalPayment('3.33', 'USD', 'Description', 'sale');
let items: PayPalItem[];
/** 
  cart = [
      {
       name: 'pen', 
       qty: 12, 
       price: '2.00'}, 
      {
       name: 'pencil', 
       qty: 2, 
       price: '1.00'
      }, 
      {
       name: 'box', 
       qty: 1, 
       price: '20.00'
      }
   ];
 */
cart.forEach(x => {
  items.push(new PayPalItem(x.name, x.qty, x.price, "USD"));
});
payment.items = items;
PayPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then(() => {
  //response ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in you code.

```
let payment = new PayPalPayment('3.33', 'USD', 'Description', 'sale');
```

Here in this code the total price i.e. `'3.33'` must be equal to the price of the cart array, i.e. in the cart array the sum of `(qty*price)` of all products must be equal to the price in the following part

```
let payment = new PayPalPayment('3.33', 'USD', 'Description', 'sale');
```

Comment: it's late though but my problem was of with multiple items i was able to complete the single item checkout without any issue but there was problem with when i was trying to add multiple items like cart system there might be some updates which are fixed now but i have not checked in a while

Answer (score -1):

This is a issue in cordova paypal plugin. You cannot add multiple items. Please refer https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin/issues/178

Comment: i am aware of this, after the complete research i have added bounty on this, and if you do check the java files there is mentioned multiple items array